# jquery ajax delete record

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

I am trying to delete a value in a comma seperated string in a table.  The script that does this (delete_url.php) works fine on it's own if I set the post values manually, but I'm having a problem passing those values to the script with ajax.  In the page that I want to pass the values from I have:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {

                 $('.delete').click(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '../scripts/delete_link.php', 
            data: 'link=' + $(this).attr('data_link') + '&topic_pk=' + $(this).attr('data_topic'),
            success: function() {

            }
        });        
    });
            });
        </script>
```

And:

```
<a class='delete_link' href='#' data_link='<?php echo urlencode($link); ?>' data_topic='<?php echo $topic_pk; ?>' onclick="return confirm('Are you certain you want to DELETE this link?')";><img src="../images/delete.png" width="16" height="16" alt="delete" title="delete this link" border='0' /></a>
```

I probably should be using json, but not sure of the correct way to do this.  Thanks for any help.

Comment: If you are storing multiple values in one database column, **you are doing it wrong!**

Comment: Sorry, but that is not the problem, and the only way that I can do this.

Comment: I just saw the error, should be $('.delete_link').click(function() {

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have updated my code with the folowing and now works deleting the record and removing the entry on the page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('table#delTable td a.delete_link').click(function()
    {
        if (confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this row?"))
        {
            var id = $(this).parent().parent().attr('id');
            var data = 'id=' + id ;
            var parent = $(this).parent().parent();

            $.ajax(
            {
                   type: "POST",
                   url: '../scripts/delete_link.php',
                   data: 'link=' + $(this).attr('data_link') + '&topic_pk=' + $(this).attr('data_topic') + '&topic_introduction=' + $(this).attr('data_introduction'),
                   cache: false,

                   success: function()
                   {
                    parent.fadeOut('fast', function() {$(this).remove();});
                   }
             });
        }
    });
});

 </script>
```

And the table:

```
<table id='delTable' width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="5">
<?php 
if(!empty($retrieved_links)){
    foreach($retrieved_links as $link){
?>
  <tr>
    <td><?php echo $link; ?></td>
    <td width='16' align='center' valign='middle'><a class='delete_link' href='#' data_link='<?php echo urlencode($link); ?>' data_topic='<?php echo $topic_pk; ?>' data_introduction='<?php echo $topic_introduction; ?>'><img src="../images/delete.png" width="16" height="16" alt="delete" title="delete this link" border='0' /></a></td>
  </tr>
<?php }
}
?>
</table>
```

And delete_link.php:

```
<?php
require_once('../connection/connect.php');
mysql_select_db($database, $connection);

$link = urldecode($_POST['link']);
$topic_pk = $_POST['topic_pk'];
$topic_introduction = $_POST['topic_introduction'];


if(!empty($link)){

$query_get_topic = "SELECT * FROM topic WHERE topic_pk = '$topic_pk'";
$result_get_topic = mysql_query($query_get_topic, $connection) or die(mysql_error());
$row_get_topic = mysql_fetch_assoc($result_get_topic);

$retrieved_links = explode(",", $row_get_topic['links']);   

$delete_link = array_search($link,$retrieved_links);

unset($retrieved_links[$delete_link]);
$updated_links = mysql_real_escape_string(implode(',',$retrieved_links));

$links_body = str_replace(',', '<p>', $updated_links);
$topic = $topic_introduction . '<p>' . $links_body;

$query = "UPDATE topic SET links = '$updated_links', topic = '$topic' WHERE topic_pk = '$topic_pk'";
$result = mysql_query($query, $connection) or die(mysql_error());
}
mysql_close();
?>
```